# Control hundreds of game objects by non Monobehavior script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'll give real-world example: Let's say there is an NPC game object, which is walking around the world/scene.

This NPC is getting followed by hundreds or even thousands of other objects, meaning that when NPC changes direction, all other objects will also change their direction.

I do this by creating hundreds of objects in Unity inspector and also each object gets a mono behavior script. This works but of course, it has a big performance impact.

Is there any other more efficient way for multiple objects to follow another object, without running them on Monobehavior?

Comment: Yes, a single monobehavior somewhere which tracks the thousands of `Transform`s and moves them at once. Or look into ECS.

Comment: [Unity DOTS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C56bbgtPr_w) is worth looking into.

Comment: As stated previously look into DOTS, this isn't me, but there is a youtuber named CodeMonkey he has a series where he does ECS, and then he adds the Job System, and burst compiler to it.  I would high recommend checking out his videos.

Comment: As said, ECS works precisely well with this situation. Each NPC would be an entity and all would have the same follow behaviour (system). That architecture, coupled with the burst compiler, should highly increase the performance of your NPCs, I'd say that if their code is based just on following, you could have about 1000 of them with 100+ FPS.

Comment: Note the [Boids/ fish swarm samples](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/EntityComponentSystemSamples/tree/master/ECSSamples/Assets/Advanced/Boids) of Unity DOTS contains specifically an approach to following targets. A word of warning, Unity DOTS is kind of a work in progress; I suspect it will become more streamlined in the future.